# Image attribute height/width auto causes performance rendering?

Tags: html, css, image

Now I face a problem with defining image attribute height and width as I don't know its dimension from the server. Then I think about assigning `width`/`height` to `auto`.

e.g.

```
img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

but I am concerning about rendering performance images without specific `width`/`height`. I would like front end developers here to help with this concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey now define your img `width` in `100%`

as like this

```
<div class="imgtagcss">
<img src="xxx.jpg" >
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.imgtagcss{
width:xxx;
}
.imgtagcss img{
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: but my image has been resized! I want it to be same as its actual size. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Give width and height has a 100% in css. So when css is loaded all the image tag will be setted to 100%. This doesn't give any performance effect.